# Evaluate the integral $H(y)=\int_{z=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^4+zy}\,dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> - $y\geq0$ define $$H(y)=\int_{z=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^4+zy}\,dz$$  Show that $H$ is a continuous function of $y$ and show $\lim\limits_{y \to +\infty}H(y)=0$.

Comment: In general, if $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,x]$, then $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is continuous. Note that the integrand is continuous in $[1,+\infty]$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Are you sure you read the problem correctly?  $f(a)$ is not an antiderivative of $1/(x^4+ax)$.

Comment: I'm puzzled about that as well. Are thinking in some change of variables?

Comment: sorry, my last comment was to @PeterTamaroff

Comment: @leo Maybe I scanned through the problem too fast =).

Comment: nour: Why are you vandalizing your own question?

Comment: @Nour: To ask a new question, click on the ask question button.  Do not edit existing questions to change them into new ones.  I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: nour: You did it again! How are people supposed to know that $f$ is $H$ and $a$ is $y$ and that there is now a question about continuity? Please stop defacing your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a brute force method where we explicitly find the function $f(a)$.
$$f(a) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\log(1+a)}{3a} & \text{if }a >0\\ \dfrac13 & \text{if }a=0 \end{cases}$$
This can be obtained as shown below. We have that for $a>0$, $$\dfrac1{x^4+ax} = \dfrac1{x(x^3+a)} = \dfrac1{ax} - \dfrac{x^2}{a(a+x^3)}$$
Hence, $$f(a) = \int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^4+ax} = \int_1^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1{ax} - \dfrac{x^2}{a(a+x^3)} \right) dx = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_1^{R} \left(\dfrac1{ax} - \dfrac{x^2}{a(a+x^3)} \right) dx$$
The first integral $$I_1 = \int_1^{R} \dfrac{dx}{ax} = \dfrac{\log(R)}a.$$
The second integral $$I_2 = \dfrac1{3a} \int_1^{R} \dfrac{3x^2dx}{(a+x^3)} = \left. \dfrac1{3a} \log(a+x^3) \right \rvert_{1}^{R} = \dfrac{\log(a+R^3) - \log(a+1)}{3a}$$
Putting these together, we get that
\begin{align}
f(a) & = I_1 - I_2\\
& = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \left(\dfrac{\log(R)}a - \left( \dfrac{\log(a+R^3) - \log(a+1)}{3a}\right) \right)\\
& = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\log(R^3)-\log(a+R^3) + \log(a+1)}{3a}\\
& = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\log \left(\dfrac{R^3}{a+R^3} \right) + \log(a+1)}{3a}\\
& = \dfrac{\log (1) + \log(a+1)}{3a}\\
& = \dfrac{\log(a+1)}{3a}\\
\end{align}
If $a=0$, then $f(0) = \displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^4} = \dfrac13$. Hence, we have that $$f(a) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\log(1+a)}{3a} & \text{if }a >0\\ \dfrac13 & \text{if }a=0 \end{cases}$$
Clearly, $f$ is a continous function of $a$ for all $a \geq 0$ and $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} f(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply here the rule for differentiating under the integral sign of Leibnitz:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{1}{x^4+ax}\right)dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{-x}{(x^4+ax)^2}dx$$, and since $\,f(a)\,$ derivable then it is continuous.

For the limit you can use the dominated convergence theorem:$$a>0\,\,,\,x\in [1,\infty)\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{x^4+ax}\leq\frac{1}{x^4}\Longrightarrow $$$$\Longrightarrow\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^4+ax}dx=\int_1^\infty\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+ax}dx=0$$because $\,\displaystyle{\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^4}dx}\,$ exists

Comment: Why we have to do DCT here? I think it is enough to write f(a) explicitly as done by Marvis and conclude that lim f(a)=0. Do you have a point to go to the DCT? Thank you

Comment: Using the DCT is much easier.

Comment: @Nour Bless your heart if you think that what Marvis did is easier that using the DCT as above, though I might agree it is perhaps more elementary and, definitely, it ie enough. DCT was my first thought here and, as it happens, it can make things pretty easier.

Comment: If DCT isn't your thing, just use AGM to see that $1/(x^4 + ax) \le 2/\sqrt{ax^5}$, so $f(a) \ll 1/\sqrt{a}$.